# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in code PHP (WORDPRESS)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have a error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/dgsite81/public_html/dgprint/wp-content/themes/dgprint/taxonomy-product_category.php on line 197

CODE PHP:

```
<?php 
    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
    $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
    $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
    $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
    $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
    $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

           $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5");
             <ul>  //here is the line with error 
                <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?>
                    <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
             </ul>
?>
```

How can I fix this error? I did not realize what I should add parentheses and where exactly.

Comment: You cant just write HTML into PHP Code... After the `$fields` line add `?>` and after the `</ul>` add `<?php` again.

Comment: add `?>` before the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing closing tag for php, so php automatically tries to parse it.

Correct code:

```
$fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5"); ?>
<ul>  //here is the line with error
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing PHP and HTML.  You need to enclose your PHP code in `<?php ?>` brackets...

```
$fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5");
?> <!-- This tells the PHP parser to stop parsing as PHP code -->
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using HTML inside a php tag, you can either do `echo "<ul>"` or close PHP and then do `ul` like this:

```
<?php 
                    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
                    $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                    $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
                    $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
                    $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                    $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                           $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5"); ?> <------- this thing here
                             <ul>  //here is the line with error 
                                <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?> 
                                    <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                             </ul>

                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to close the php script it before that line

```
 <?php 
                    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
                    $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                    $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);                      
                    $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);                 
                    $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                    $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                           $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5");
                             ?>
                             <ul>
                                <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?>
                                    <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                             </ul> 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you used HTML tags directly in a PHP code. Try this:

```
<?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
    $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);
    $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);
    $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
    $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

    $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5");
?>
     <ul>
        <?php foreach($fiedls as $value) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is basic syntax please document yourself better...
try this:

```
 <?php
                    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
                    $cat_content = get_field('category_content', $queried_object);
                    $imagine2= get_field('imagine2',$queried_object);
                    $imagine3= get_field('imagine3',$queried_object);
                    $imagine4= get_field('imagine4',$queried_object);
                    $imagine5= get_field('imagine5',$queried_object);

                           $fields = array("cat_content","imagine2","imagine3","imagine4","imagine5");
                            echo '
                             <ul>';
                                foreach($fiedls as $value){
                                    echo '
                                    <li>'.$value.'</li>';
                                }
                            echo '
                            </ul>';

?>
```